# Dynamics AX 2012 X++ Run Method on Launch of a View (Init?)

Tags: view, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Anyone aware of an override that can be used to run a method whenever a view is launched in AX 2012 x++?

The intent is to use a class method to update some values in a table before the view runs its query.

I don't see an init method or anything along those lines in the available overrides.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a scenario in which this might needed and clarify why the table update cannot be triggered from the code right before the view is used?

Comment: There is nothing on a view in AX 2012 that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this in the exact way that you are asking.

There is no override that will be launched because the view "code" is not x++, it is SQL code. The view is a precompiled SQL query that acts as a table and is stored in the SQL database.  Now you might notice Views are implemented in x++ as inheriting from the Common object. Thus they have similar behavior as tables. Tables do not have methods that run before being "launched" as you say, but are queried using select update delete etc. Unfortunately views do not have the same event list in the MorphX designer as tables do.

Perhaps to solve your requirement, instead of looking for an override on the View itself, look for an override in the specific location that the view is being used. A simple example could be this: if the View is used as a datasource on a form, you would override the `executeQuery()` method on the form's datasource (which would be your view), and modify certain things before the query on the view is executed. This is obviously difficult to manage as a View could be used anywhere, so you would have to pay close attention to where the view is being used.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  This is what I expected, but thought it was worth asking.  If the view were being called from code, those would be really easy.  Simply call the method before running the query.  In this case, building views to help a customer export some data, and they are simply calling them from the AOT--and I was concerned they would forget to run the update job first.  They will just have to remember to do that step.  : )